# Trying to move a huge WordPress site to MicroSoft Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-git-deployment

I'm trying to move a large WordPress site ( with uploads directory size 15GB) to Azure.

I created a WordPress site from gallery and then

1. I tried creating a git repository, but it doesnt work for the large
   number of files I have.
2. I tried zipping the uploads directory and moving it to azure from terminal using ftp. It did not work either.
3. SCP is not an option as websites on azure do not have shell access.

Can anyone guide me on how to move the site to azure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Azure Web Sites support that much disk space.  I would suggest moving all of your content into blob storage, and use this plugin with wordpress:

http://msopentech.com/opentech-projects/windows-azure-storage-for-wordpress/

For more info on blob storage:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

If you're looking to just pick up the site and drop it as is, you could use a virtual machine:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/

Happy coding :)